# aws lambda rangeerror: maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: aws-lambda

In the last few days, we have moved some services of ours from ECS container to lambda, and they are working ALMOST perfect.
We have an error thrown from time to time from lambda:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

When we used ECS dockers we used to run node with 2 parameters which resolved this issue:

```
node --stack-size=65500 --max_old_space_size=5000
```

I didn’t find a way to do it in lambda configuration.

Comment: Did you try allocating large memory to Lambda? Like 1GB to see what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

eventually, it was a node.js issue with spread operator:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16870